# Is ungentle exit() acceptable way to handle critical error?

Tags: c, error-handling, crash, pthreads, exit

In multi threaded C program, where due to critical program error, gentle program exit would be really difficult to implement, is hard exit using `exit_group();` function acceptable way to stop program execution?

I mean really critical and unrecoverable error up to point where any further operation could potentially damage filesystem and database. I'm a bit concerned about potential resources leakage. In fact not even leaking but locking - so that process couldn't be restarted without reboot because some resource would remain reserved.

OS in question is modern Linux (4.x kernel)

Comment: This depends entirely on a) the os you use and b) which kind of resources you use. Many resources are freed and unlocked automatically on process exit, but others may persist (sysv shm/semaphores for example, lock files, etc pp). For sysv semaphore operations for example you may specify `SEM_UNDO` to undo the operation on process exit

Comment: What kind of locks are you concerned with?  Are you using any type of shared memory, or is the locking happening strictly between the threads in the process being killed?

Comment: @dbush I'm mostly concerned about inotify watches and sqlite database. Because FUSE handles ungentle crash quite well. It's designed to do exactly that. Also semaphores and synchronization resources.

Comment: @Ctx from what I understand I need `SEM_UNDO` or `pthread_mutexattr_setrobust` when I use multi process architecture or I kill only one thread right? So that there's no deadlock in program. But If program is single process and I'm killing all threads I don't need robust mutex right?

Comment: @Lapsio Depends if you use pthread mutexes or sysv semaphores. These are two different mechanisms. Judging from what you write, sysv semaphores with SEM_UNDO look more appropriate

Comment: If your program can get into a state where "any further operation could potentially damage filesystem and database" you might be better off working to prevent that state (through better design of your program and the parts of it) rather than trying to work out how to terminate the program if it gets into that state.    If a program is in such a damaging state, odds are terminating the program would cause further damage.

Comment: @Peter it's state where due to filesystem i/o error program tries to handle such error by rolling back changes but that also throws i/o error so program tries to reset database and re-read filesystem and set up all `inotify` watches again but that fails again with some i/o error so program ends up in inconsistent state it can't escape because any attempt to fix it results in i/o error. Including attempt to re-read filesystem. At this point any operation will only result in further desynchronization. So my question is "what can I do if there's error in error handling of error in error handling"

Comment: So the means of recovery from a significant filesystem error is to attempt more filesystem operations on the same device. That's the design problem - if recovery from a filesystem error is to attempt more operations on the same filesystem, the program cannot avoid a cascade like you describe. You need to prevent that, not deal with it.  There are all sorts of strategies for implementing fault tolerance (e.g. maintaining replicants of database on distinct devices and, when a failure occurs, swap out the failing replicant and swap in a working one).

Comment: @Peter I oversimplified it a bit - program implements transactional multi target replication - when change occurs it's written to multiple storage mediums - database, files, filesystem attributes, etc. Situation I'm trying to handle is transaction rollback failure - when one replication target accepts change, second target fails to accept change and then first one fails to revert accepted change. We end up with inconsistent cluster - the only way to sync it is to rebuild slave mediums basing on some authoritative medium. But if doing that fails as well, it's kind of unrecoverable error.

Comment: @Peter commiting any more writes to such cluster would only result in further desync and more cluster corruption. That's why I want to terminate program in such case. It's consumer grade application. Meant to run mostly on single drive and run local sqlite db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exit` runs cleanup handlers registered with `atexit` or `at_quick_exit`, flushes stdio streams, and performs lots of other cleanup.  For truly critical errors (such as potentially exploitable memory corruption), `_exit` would be a safer choice.  In older glibc versions, `abort` (or `assert(false)`) flushed stdio streams as well.  Another alternative would be to execute an undefined instruction.